# Can any one compare AWS Lex v1 and Lex v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

Hi I am new to AWS Lex service. But I would like to know the what's makes the difference between v1 and V2.
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Python boto3. I wanted know what is the extra features in Lex V2 than V1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read through this migration guide that provides some details on what the differences are between Lex V1 and V2.

[Amazon Lex Migration Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/migration.html)

Here's another article that's worth a read.

[A quick guide to understand the design difference between Amazon Lex Version 1 and Version 2](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/quick-guide-understand-design-difference-between-lex-wong/)